# New entity in repeated StructuredProperty stored as a _BaseValue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a `HUser` model (derived from Google's `User` class) which in turn contains 0 to n instances of social accounts. These accounts can be references to Facebook, Twitter or LinkedIn accounts. I have built an `Account` model, and defined a `StructuredProperty` in my `User` model with `repeated=True`, like this:

```
class Account(ndb.Expando):
    account_type = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, choices=['fb', 'tw', 'li'])
    account_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    access_token = ndb.StringProperty()
    ...

class HUser(User):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, validator=validate_email)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    accounts = ndb.StructuredProperty(Account, repeated=True)
```

If I only add Facebook or LinkedIn accounts to my user, everything works as expected. But the strange thing is, whenever I add a Twitter account, all subsequent accounts I add to that same user are stored as `_BaseValue(Account())`, and not `Account()` directly. So in my pages where I try to fetch accounts, I usually get errors like:

> AttributeError: '_BaseValue' object has no attribute 'account_type'

I've read that these _BaseValue conversions are a bug in Google's ndb source code, but how can I get rid of it? Currently I'm using this awful workaround to bypass exceptions:

```
if type(account) == _BaseValue:
    account = account.b_val
    logging.warn("WARN: %s account %s was of type _BaseValue..." % (account.account_type, account.account_id))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How are you accessing your repeated property? ndb models store properties as `_BaseValue`s and convert "seamlessly" (unfortunately not always the case) to your type (called the UserValue in ndb). Because of this, you have to be careful about how you store properties outside of your model. Consider this:

```
myUser = HUser(...)
accounts = myUser.accounts
myUser.put()
accounts[0] # This is a _BaseValue(Account)
myUser.accounts[0] # This is an Account
```

This is an [open bug](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=208) on the ndb issue tracker.

Comment: I can't exactly remember if I was doing such things, but I might have been. Meanwhile, because of another problem (which you also helped me to solve here on SO), I had to change my design. These changes significantly reduced the amount of `put()` in my code, particularly when managing Twitter accounts. I found the bug you are referring to before posting my question, but I didn't quite understand its meaning and implications. Your answer makes it a little bit clearer. So, tu sum up, to avoid this problem in the future, I need to avoid working on local *copies* of ndb entities, is that right?

Comment: I think the key is that you should avoid working on local copies of ndb **properties**. As long as you directly access the property from the ndb entity, it will do the right thing.

Comment: @PatrickCostello, but what if your entity has a list of keys that you want to enumerate through to operate on? E.g. for job_key in ndb_file.jobs: job = job_key.get()  ...  This works elsewhere in my code but not for this particular case.

Comment: This should work as long as you always write `for prop in mymodel.props:` since you are accessing the list from the ndb object. What you cant do is: `props = mymodel.props` then `for prop in props`.