# Extraneous _BaseValue() when handling repeated property in GAE Ndb Datastore

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Say I have an Ndb entity that goes like this:

```
class MyEntity(ndb.Model):
    name = StringProperty()
    tags = StringProperty(repeated=True)
```

I will create an entity:

```
>>> e = MyEntity(name='test')
>>> e.tags = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> e.tags
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
>>> t = e.tags
>>> t
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Seems ok up to that point.  Now I put the entity:

```
>>> e.put()
>>> t
[_BaseValue('aaa'), _BaseValue('bbb'), _BaseValue('ccc')]
```

Strange...

Now I print the original attribute:

```
>>> e.tags
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

It's back to normal.  Now for variable t:

```
>>> t
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

Normal too...

This issue [New entity in repeated StructuredProperty stored as a _BaseValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184888/new-entity-in-repeated-structuredproperty-stored-as-a-basevalue), is similar.   It says this is a known bug.   But since it is from 2014, I would expect the bug to have been fixed by now.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, a Datastore attritute's 'base value' is a value such as would be serialized to     and deserialized from Cloud Datastore. For storage, a base value gets wrapped in a _BaseValue() and then _store_value() is called. More related detail can be found on the "Source code for google.appengine.ext.ndb.model" [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model). 
To make sure this error gets properly addressed, you are encouraged to open a similar issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), where it will surely get addressed and fixed, and you'll be able to follow developments.